# How to export from Word to PDF without losing URLs?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

Is there a way to export a Word document to the PDF document without losing the URLs that are present in the original text?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `File` > `Save & Send` > `Create PDF/XPS Document` works in Word 2010. The same functionality is available in a [Microsoft Add-in for Word 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7).

Adobe Acrobat Pro's Word add-in (and PDF printer) also worked, and there is a setting in its preferences, `Add Links` (enabled by default). However, unlike the built-in add-in, the link came up as standard black text (clickable link). There's probably a setting somewhere to change that.

It all depends on the converter you use.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this and just found the answer for me.

1. In Word, go to **Save as PDF** → **Options** &rarr
2. Uncheck **ISO 19005-1 Compliant**, click **OK**
3. Publish.

Both the table of contents headings/links were clickable in the PDF and so were the hyperlinks.

#### Notes about what I'm running:

- Word 2007 on Windows Home
- Do have Adobe Acrobat installed, but didn't use that plug-in for this.
- PC